# Google Apps Scripts - a needed parent folder has been deleted

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a GSuite organization linked to Google Cloud and all the Google services (Goole Script included). In this case, from Google [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects), I should have a fixed project hierarchy in Google Cloud linked to Google Scripts:

> For G Suite customers, default GCP projects fall under the Organization root > system-gsuite > apps-script folder in the Cloud Platform Resource Hierarchy. For non-G Suite customers, default GCP projects are unparented in the Resource Hierarchy.

The hierarchy has been accidentally deleted and folders/projects cannot be recovered anymore. Every time I try to run a script (even new) it gives the following exception

> Failed to create your script's Google Cloud Platform project, because a needed parent folder has been deleted. Please contact your organization administrator about recovering the folder. For more information, see the Cloud Platform Resource Hierarchy requirements at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects.

Of course, I tried recreating the same hierarchy but the error persists.
I also don't have the possibility to change the project linked to the script.

Any advice?

Comment: Since you have a G Suite organization and account, you should contact [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) They'll be happy to assist you and will be able to access your data to see what's going on and how to fix it.

Comment: I did it but it's out of their support scope. They told me this post is the right way to communicate with Google Engineers.

Comment: I understand, What was it the folder held? the project itself?

Comment: The folder contained the projects but even creating a new script (and recreating the hierarchy) I receive the same exception.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project, it could be that scripts are getting attached to the old one by default

Comment: Yes, same behavior.

Comment: I was able to replicate this with a file instead of a project, and there is one way of accessing it, try searching for `is:unorganized` in the Drive UI, it should show files that are "missing" like this. I believe you might need ownership to be able to see them, but try nonetheless.

Comment: I did it but I don't understand how this could help me.

Comment: did the project show up when you seached for that?

Comment: no, I'm talking about a [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com) project, not a file saved in Google Drive.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had misunderstood, that also explains why G Suite support redirected you here, they do not cover this, you have to contact [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) instead, they will be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE -** I recreated the correct hierarchy and opened a case to Google Cloud support. Immediately after recreating the hierarchy I couldn't run scripts but after Cloud Support intervention I managed to do it, they probably changed something internally, they didn't specify what.